# How to make the entire menu appear when hovering over a single menu item?

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I am trying to make the **entire menu** including submenu items for every menu item appear whenever I hover over one of the menu items. This is a menu design popular in Korea but I cannot find an explanation online on how to do it. Can anyone offer some advice or pointers on how to do this? Thank you.

This is one of the websites that uses the design I mention: https://www.saga121.com/

Answer (score 0):

a sample example.
hover over list 2,appear submenu.

```css
li{
  float:left;
  list-style:none;
  width: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.ul2{
  display:none;
}

.li2{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.li2:hover .ul2{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul1">
  <li>1</li>
  <li class="li2">2
    <ul class="ul2">
      <li>3</li>
      <li class="li4">4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```